# backing up and restoring .sqlite file with Core Data and externally stored images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I couldn't think of a better way to phrase this question, so let me clarify:

I'm storing many things in Core Data, some of which are images stored as binary data.  These images have been set to allow for external storage, meaning, from what I can gather, that Core Data takes care of storing these pictures elsewhere on disk rather than inside the database itself if they are too large (> 1MB?). I am also trying to build a simple backup/restore system for this database using File Sharing - clicking "backup" copies my .sqlite file from my Library folder to my Documents folder (under a different name), allowing the user access through iTunes (to store wherever they please), and clicking "restore" looks for a backup file in the Documents folder, deletes the active .sqlite file in the Library folder and replaces it with the backup.

The problem arises when an image is deleted from Core Data, but then I want to restore my database to a time when that image still existed.  When I delete that image using Core Data, I presume both the path to the image that is stored in the database and the image itself stored elsewhere are both deleted.  But, when I restore my old database by bringing the .sqlite file back, only the path to the image exists - the image itself was stored externally, so it's nowhere to be found.

First of all, is this a reasonable approach to backing up and restoring a database under Core Data, or is there a clear reason that I shouldn't be going about it by copying the underlying .sqlite file back and forth?  Second, can anyone provide advice on how I might go about allowing Core Data to take care of external storage while still having a way to back up those images?  I realize that I could probably store images manually, thus allowing me to back up an image folder along with my .sqlite file, but I do like the simplicity of having Core Data manage this for me, so I'm just wondering if there is any better way to do this backup/restore thing.

Comment: I agree the "external storage"option is really handy but when wanting to backup the entire core data db it makes things much more complex than to simply remotely save the sqlite file. 
Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: yes. what's your solution for this backup. backup is my single reason for choosing to use core data for blobs. but otherwise there is no advantage -- with many disadvantages. in fact, im getting rid of it now.

Comment: Customize UIDocument, create a file structure that contains a part for coreDdata, and a part for images and their paths... When opening the file compare and rewrite/write the needed images to their positions... Know it's late but could help. If you test and it works please post an answer, believe this will help.